# Sign in using google with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I want allow users to be able login to my system using their Google account. 
So I am working with Google Sign-in with JavaScript.

My issue is when users open login page login by Google is working automatically when login page load. I want user to login else when he pressed login by Google button

The is login button

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-longtitle="false" data-onsuccess="Google_signIn" data-theme="dark" data-width="200"></div>
```

this is javascript code

```js
function Google_signIn(googleData) 
{
    var profile = googleData.getBasicProfile(); //get google profile details


    //update to database
//  var islogged=googleData.isSignedIn();//alert(islogged);
//  if(islogged==false)
    update_user_data(profile);

}


function update_user_data(response) 
{alert('ok');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html >
<head>
<!-- start: Meta -->
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<!-- start: Mobile Specific -->

<!-- end: Mobile Specific -->

<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="636950137786-j3siaftgshtf9iajhfgfdxhgjf1.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_login_box">
<div class="g-signin2" data-longtitle="false" data-onsuccess="Google_signIn" data-theme="dark" data-width="200"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

how can I make this code working only when user pressed on button

Comment: I dont understand your question.   It works except when what??

Comment: @DaImTo it working every time user reload login page even if he does not press login by google button

Comment: Please fix any errors in the console if the code is executable. If it is not, remove the `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->` The sandbox does not allow cookies or ajax

Comment: Do you want the users to see the login button everytime they refresh the page even if they have already logged in before?

Comment: @ِAnthony no my code is working automatically when   user reload the login page in other word user is login by his google account even if he does not want to login by google account ,because the code is working when the page is loaded without pressing any button \